# Is it possible to increase the speed of appending files in pandas based on generated combinations?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, loops, combinations

I need some help in figuring out a way to increase the performance of the below python code.

I am calculating the number of duplicates between a group of excel files based on certain combinations. To achieve this I have used a python script that generates all possible combinations that 10 files can be grouped in 5 groups. Then based on the generated combinations I have continued the script to append those files and calculate the number of duplicates in each group.

Example:

Sample output of the entire script ( combinations for 10 files combined in 5 groups is only a sample)

[image]
The first part of my script generates all possible combinations the 10 excel files can be grouped together in 5 groups, example:

```
Combination 1: (File 1) (File 2) (File 3) (File 4) (File 5 File 6 File 7 File 8 File 9 File 10)
Combination 2: (File 1 File 2) (File 3) (File 4) (File 5) (File 6 File 7 File 8 File 9 File 10)
Combination 3: etc...
```

```
def sorted_k_partitions(seq, k):

n = len(seq)
groups = []  # a list of lists, currently empty

def generate_partitions(i):
    if i >= n:
        yield list(map(tuple, groups))
    else:
        if n - i > k - len(groups):
            for group in groups:
                group.append(seq[i])
                yield from generate_partitions(i + 1)
                group.pop()

        if len(groups) < k:
            groups.append([seq[i]])
            yield from generate_partitions(i + 1)
            groups.pop()

result = generate_partitions(0)
```

The second part of my code appends the files and calculates the total duplicates based on each combination:

```
for k in 1, 5: #k is the number of groups i want to distribute the files into
for groups in sorted_k_partitions(seq, k):  #sorted_k_partitions gets the combinations
    groupnumberofduplicates = 0
    for group in groups:                 #groups is each combination(ex: Combination 1), group is each group in a combination (ex: Group 1 in ss)
        ids = pd.DataFrame()
        for file in group:
            ids = ids.append(pd.read_excel(file))
        numberofduplicates = ids.duplicated().sum()
        groupnumberofduplicates = groupnumberofduplicates + numberofduplicates
    grouplist = grouplist.append({"k":k, "groupname" : groups, "groupnumberofduplicates": groupnumberofduplicates}, ignore_index =True )
```

Taking into consideration that each file has 1 column with 100,000 rows the script is really slow but it's working. Its getting slow in the second part of the code I showed above mainly because there are many combinations that the script is going into each one and getting the number of duplicates. The second reason is that the number of rows in each file is huge. Is there a way to make this faster?

Thank you and really appreciated anyone that could help.

Update: number of rows is no longer an issue for the speed. Found a way to fix that. The loop is the only reason for long processing time now.

Comment: Have you counted how many ways 10 things can be divided into 5 groups?  The number is astronomical.  If we JUST limit it to four groups of 1 and a group of 6, there are 5,040.

Comment: Hi Tim. I agree the number of combinations is huge and with every file added it will increase exponentially. The purpose of the script is to find the combination with the least amount of duplicates in a reasonable amount of time. Any suggestions from your end?

Comment: No, because we don't know what you're looking for.  Are you looking for duplicated FILES?  Are you looking for duplicated ROWS?  Are you, perhaps, looking to do a merge sort, where you merge all of the files and produce only the unique rows?  That's not hard.

Comment: Sorry maybe the goal of the script is not clear. I am looking for the combination of 10 excel files distributed in 5 groups that has the least amount of duplicate rows. Example: if combination 1 has File 1 & File 2 in Group 1, these two files will be merged and the number of duplicate rows will be calculated. The same will be done to the rest of the groups and the number of duplicates will be summed up. The combination with the least total number of duplicates is the one I am want to find.